# How can I add a command to the Bash history without executing it?

Tags: bash, command-history

Every now and then it would be useful to add a command directly to the history in Bash without actually executing it. So far the closed thing I have found is adding a `#` in front of it and hitting return. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`history -s` *command*

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to run a similar command to this from a script?  I have a script `./resize-images.sh` whose final line indicates a command you should run to undo the changes, it would be really useful if instead the script could add the command to my history so I just hit `up-enter` if i needed to undo

Comment: @BenPage: Look at both answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112354/history-stops-working-when-run-inside-bash-script.

Comment: See `help history` for details.

Answer (score 13):

`history -s` *command*

You can even bind a keystroke to do this for you. You can enter this at a Bash prompt:

```
bind '"\C-q": "\C-a history -s \C-j"'
```

or add this to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-q": "\C-a history -s \C-j"
```

then you can type something and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> and it will be added to the history without being executed. The space before "history" causes the `history` command itself to *not* be added to the history if your `HISTCONTROL` variable contains `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`. Another keystroke could be chosen instead of "\C-q".

Comment: `C-a` is a `Readline Key Binding` to move to beginning of the line (from `man bash`). I could not find `C-j` there but it seems it 's like `ENTER`.

Comment: @Martian2020: `C-j` is bound to the Readline function `accept-line` as is `C-m`. You can find `aacept-line` in `man bash`. By the way, `C-j` is newline and `C-m` is carriage return.

Comment: I could not find `C-j` in `man bash` on my Linux Mint based system (and `C-m` too), `accept-line (Newline, Return)` as opposed to `beginning-of-line (C-a)`. Therefore I've written 'it seems'. One may try to look at bash source, but it is not high priority for me lol.

Comment: @Martian2020: `man ascii` will show that `C-j` is newline and `C-m` is CR (return). These are basic well-known, well-defined characters that should never be remapped.

Comment: Again on my system `man ascii` has `012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)`, `This  page is part of release 5.10 of the Linux man-pages project.` BTW. No `C-j`. And I could not find mentioning about `Ctrl-J` on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. Seems to me this knowledge is getting lost...

Comment: @Martian2020: All control characters are offset from the corresponding letter by decimal 64 (hex 40). See this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character. Note that it uses another common representation: `^J`. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#ASCII where `^J`, "Line Feed" and "end-of-line" are used.

Comment: Thanks. I've already used your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77449501/14557599 to store output of a command. I suggest to add quoting to prevent pathname expansion (noted it for `ll` output but could be relevant here too).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to come up with anything shorter than a one character "command", so we really need to go to the keystroke level. With my bash setup and an US keyboard what you do now takes:

1. Go to beginning of line: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>: +1 instruction, +2 keypresses
2. Add `#` (needs <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>): +1 instruction, +2 keypress
3. Appending it to the history with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>: +1 instruction, +1 keypress

so in total 3 instructions, 5 keypresses.

Using <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> does the same in 1 instruction, 2 keypresses.

YMMV depending on your keyboard layout and bash configuration.

Comment: The problem isn't the number of key presses, but that "#command" gets stored in the history, instead of the intended "command".

Comment: It's nice that "#command" gets stored in the history file as it lets you know that the command wasn't actually executed.  This might be nice if you later wanted to review what commands you entered in order to figure out a problem.

Comment: @Grumbel, @Marnix: Agreed, I didn't answer the question to the letter but showed how to make what he does now even faster. Personally I think using `#command` is way quicker than `history -s command`, and also very easy to use if you map `history-search-backward/-forward` properly. But it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Spiff's answer, you can put the *results* of the command into the history, not just the command itself. For example, I often like a date time stamp in the history list:

```
> alias dts='history -s $(echo -n "### "; date)'
> dts
> history
...
45 ### Fri Sep 29 08:26:52 PM UTC 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be useful to add a command even from a subprocess (which makes to lose the current command):

```
echo "the command" >> ~/.bash_history
```